# How to NOT cache an NSImage loaded byReferencingURL

Tags: cocoa, swift, caching, nsimage

How would I load an `NSImage` from URL without caching it? It should always be re-loaded from the remote source. But even if I am not connected to the internet, I end up with a valid image. Setting the cache mode to the already loaded image does not have any effect.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png")
let img = NSImage(byReferencingURL: url!)
img.cacheMode = NSImageCacheMode.Never
NSLog("Found image with size \(img.size)")
```

When I run this snippet in a playground, it actually never caches, even if I set `NSImageCacheMode.Always`.

But when I run this snippet in my application, it always returns a valid image, **even if I'm not connected to the internet**.

I know I could simply use a cache buster parameter with a random number or timestamp. But this is a theoretical question and I'm interested in how to prevent caching in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue in objc as well (I think, trying out this fix now).

I assume you can work around it thusly:

```
NSString *imgURL = @"http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png";
NSURL *u = [NSURL URLWithString:imgURL];

NSError *error;
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:u
                                  options:NSDataReadingUncached
                                    error:&error];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:d];
```

I believe that will load from the network resource every time.

I might take a crack at swift after I do some testing to figure out if it actually works.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure this would work. In parallel to the image I am loading an XML file via `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL` and this one returned `nil` when the machine was offline. So it definitely should work with an image as well. But this is a workaround, same as adding a "cache buster" parameter to the URL. I'm surprised the image is cached in the first place when loaded from URL. What is the `cacheMode` good for? Setting it after the image is loaded has no effect - it's already cached - but how would you set it before loading from URL?

Comment: Yeah, unless setting cacheMode purged the cache for next time I totally agree the API doesn't make sense. In my case the problem was a few out of hundreds of images that are all supposed to be 480x680 were coming back at much smaller sizes but had higher DPIs. They were rendering small instead of at their actual pixel size (which turned out to be correct).